# Trouble with Ghost (blog) and Cloudfront CDN

Tags: node.js, nginx, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, ghost

I'm hosting my Ghost blog on an EC2 instance and attempting to place cloudfront in front of the blog but am running into redirect errors.

[image]

The blog works absolutely fine without cloudfront, but once it's added the problem emerges. I think it might have something to do with my SSL configuration. My `Nginx` file is set up to serve the blog over `http`:

```
upstream app_yourdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:2368;
    keepalive 8;
}

# the nginx server instance

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name mysite.com mysite;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/blog.log;

    location /blog/content/images {
        alias /var/www/ghost/content/images;
    }

    location /blog/assets {
        alias /var/www/ghost/content/themes/pluto/assets;
    }

    location ~ ^/blog/(?:ghost|signout) {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, max-age=0, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    }

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see nginx config options
    location /blog/ghost {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain/;
      # proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain/;
    expires 60m;

        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    }
 }
```

but the site itself is being served over `SSL`. This isn't a problem when the site isn't behind `cloudfront` but once it is the error occurs. What I think might be happening is `cloudfront` is stripping off some headers from the request that ghost uses to determine if the traffic is `http` or `https` but I haven't been able to confirm this.

Here's what's in my `nginx` log:

```
46.100.228.227 - - [17/Oct/2015:23:43:59 +0000] "GET /blog/ghost HTTP/1.0" 303 55 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
46.100.228.227 - - [17/Oct/2015:23:43:59 +0000] "GET /blog/ghost/ HTTP/1.0" 301 66 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
46.100.228.227 - - [17/Oct/2015:23:44:00 +0000] "GET /blog/ghost/ HTTP/1.0" 301 66 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
46.100.228.227 - - [17/Oct/2015:23:44:00 +0000] "GET /blog/ghost/ HTTP/1.0" 301 66 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
46.100.228.227 - - [17/Oct/2015:23:44:00 +0000] "GET /blog/ghost/ HTTP/1.0" 301 66 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
46.100.228.227 - - [17/Oct/2015:23:44:00 +0000] "GET /blog/ghost/ HTTP/1.0" 301 66 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
46.100.228.227 - - [17/Oct/2015:23:44:00 +0000] "GET /blog/ghost/ HTTP/1.0" 301 66 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
46.100.228.227 - - [17/Oct/2015:23:44:00 +0000] "GET /blog/ghost/ HTTP/1.0" 301 66 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
```

Any Idea what could be causing this or how to resolve? Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Several possibilities.  Did you set the [Origin Protocol Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginProtocolPolicy) to "match viewer?"  Did you configure CloudFront to [forward the host header to the origin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders)?

Comment: Try adding ``proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`` with your other proxy configs.